# Can we call a function (with parameters) in the parent smart contract from its child smart contract without making the function (in parent) payable?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, tokens

ERC20 Token Smart Contract:

```
contract ERC20token is  IERC20 {
   
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Address for address;
    
    mapping (address => uint256) public _balances;
    uint256 private _totalSupply;
    uint256 private _cap=10000;
    address public owner; 
    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;
    uint8 private _decimals;

    constructor (string memory name, string memory symbol) public {
        _name = name;
        _symbol = symbol;
        _decimals = 18;
        _mint(msg.sender, 2000);
        owner=msg.sender;
    }
    

    /* other functions */

    /**Creates `amount` tokens and assigns them to `account`, increasing
     * the total supply.
     * Requirements
     * - `to` cannot be the zero address.
     */
    function _mint(address account, uint256 _amount) public virtual {
        require(account != address(0), "ERC20: mint to the zero address");
        
        _beforeTokenTransfer(address(0), account, _amount);

        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(_amount);
        _balances[account] = _balances[account].add(_amount);
       
    }
   
    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
         if (from == address(0)) { // When minting tokens
            require(totalSupply().add(amount) <= _cap, "ERC20Capped: cap exceeded");
        }
     }
}
```

Test Smart Contract:

```
contract Test 
   {
     
     address owner; 
     ERC20token ec;
     
      constructor () public {
        owner=msg.sender; 
     }

    function Asset_mint(uint _amount) public 
    {
         // some conditions 
         ec._mint(msg.sender, _amount);
         
    }
}
```

When function `Asset_mint()` is called with an amount more than msg.sender's balance, transaction is reverted with the error:

- The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
  Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.

is it not possible to call a function in a smart contract from another smart contract by passing a numeric value?

Comment: you mean like `anotherContract.someFunction{value:<somevalue>}();` ?

Answer (score 0):

> is it not possible to call a function in a smart contract from another smart contract by passing a numeric value?

I think this is what you are driving at.

```
contract testA {

    uint public testNum;

    function someFunction() public payable returns (uint) {
        return ++testNum;
    }
}


contract testB {

    testA anotherContract;

    constructor() payable {
        anotherContract = new testA();
        console.log(address(anotherContract));
    }

    receive() external payable {}

    function getBalance() external view returns (uint) {
        uint _bal = address(this).balance;
        console.log(_bal);
        return _bal;
    }

    function callOther(uint _amountToOther) external payable returns (uint) {
        console.log("contract balance", address(this).balance);
        console.log("calling other function passing %d wei", _amountToOther);
        uint result = anotherContract.someFunction{value: _amountToOther * 1 wei}();
        console.log("other contract function call returned result", result);
        console.log("contract balance", address(this).balance);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: uint result = anotherContract.someFunction{value: _amountToOther * 1 wei}(); here value is passed to somefuntion() because its declared payable and it can receive wei or ether.

Comment: The issue I am facing is I need to call **_mint() ** in the Test contract without passing Wei or Ether to **_mint()**. Can it be done?

Comment: `callOther()` doesn't have to be payable. that's just optional. just for fun.
`someFunction()` does have to be payable if you want to send value when you call that function, which I think you did, right?

Comment: "The issue I am facing is I need to call _mint() ** in the Test contract without passing Wei or Ether to **_mint(). Can it be done?"   ---- of course. why would you have to send eth?

Comment: I forgot to initialize  **ERC20token ec**;  in **Test contarct**, that's why I was getting the following error: "The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance."  Thank you.